# Returning incorrect logical from is.nan

Tags: r, apply

I am analyzing microarray data from a publicly available database, and my output is a log-ratio matrix comparing experimental data to controls. I have discovered that one of my columns is populated with `NaN` values due to the fact that this treatment does not have a corresponding control. My data frame's (`fc_initial`) dimensions are 9049 x 647.

```
> dim(fc_initial)
[1] 9049  647
```

the column that is populated by NaN is the 580th column

```
head(fc_initial[,580])
# [1] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

summary(is.nan(fc_initial[,580]))
#    Mode    TRUE    NA's 
# logical    9049       0
```

When I try to examine this for all columns using `apply`, R incorrectly returns all `FALSE` for this column.

```
fc_num <- apply(fc_initial, 2, is.nan)
summary(fc_num[ ,580])
#    Mode   FALSE    NA's 
# logical    9049       0
```

I have visually confirmed this using view for both `fc_initial` and `fc_num`, and I have double checked that I am looking for the right column using `which()`.

```
which(fc_num, arr.ind = TRUE)
#  row col
```

`which` returns no cells showing as `TRUE`.

What am I missing? Why is R returning a column of `FALSE` for a column of values I have visually confirmed to be `TRUE`?

Comment: If `fc_initial` is indeed a data.frame, you may benefit from reading _very carefully_ the first sentence of the Details section of `?apply` and then thinking about whether `fc_initial` has a mix of character/factor/numeric columns. (i.e. consider `sapply` rather than `apply`).

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. The first column of the data frame is a list of probes as characters, which causes the behavior you pointed out. 'sapply' fixes the issue, and I will know this for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling `apply`, the dataframe is coerced to a matrix. If there are any character columns, the whole dataframe is coerced to a character matrix and all `NaN` are converted to `NA`

```
df_1 <- data.frame(a=c("a","b","c"), b=c(NaN, NaN,NaN))
df_2 <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(NaN, NaN,NaN))

as.matrix(df_1)

     a   b 
[1,] "a" NA
[2,] "b" NA
[3,] "c" NA

as.matrix(df_2)
     a   b
[1,] 1 NaN
[2,] 2 NaN
[3,] 3 NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Improvising on @cactusWoman and @joran comment:

```
## this gives count of nan's by column for your data.frame
sapply(fc_initial, function(y) sum(length(which(is.nan(y)))))
```